# Algorithmic package in two different languages in same document

Tags: languages, algorithmic

I need to write both in French and English in my document (for reasons).

And I need to write algorithms in both languages, using the algorithmic package.

Is it possible ?

If so, how can I do that ?

My setup is simple to include these

> \usepackage{algorithm}
>
> \usepackage{algorithmic}

and I write algorithms like this:

> \begin{algorithm}
>
> ```
>  \begin{algorithmic}
>   ...
>  \end{algorithmic}
> ```
>
> \end{algorithm}

I haven't specified anything about language in my document.  So it's in English by default.

Comment: Yes. Why would it not be a problem? What's your current setup? You could create two different environments, one for a French algorithm, and one for an English algorithm, and set the languages accordingly. But without much more information, "Yes" is the answer here.

Comment: OK, this wasn't really intended to be a Yes/No question.  Question is edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) provides the user with the flexibility to change things to suit their needs, albeit somewhat manually. To that end, I suggest creating a language-specific environment to manage the languages you're using, say `frenchalgorithm` and `englishalgorithm`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic,lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\newenvironment{englishalgorithm}[1][]
  {\begin{algorithm}[#1]
     \selectlanguage{english}%
     \floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}%
     \renewcommand{\algorithmicif}{\textbf{if}}%
     \renewcommand{\algorithmicthen}{\textbf{then}}%
     \renewcommand{\algorithmicend}{\textbf{end}}%
     % Set other language requirements
  }
  {\end{algorithm}}
\newenvironment{frenchalgorithm}[1][]
  {\begin{algorithm}[#1]
     \selectlanguage{french}%
     \floatname{algorithm}{Algorithme}%
     \renewcommand{\algorithmicif}{\textbf{si}}%
     \renewcommand{\algorithmicthen}{\textbf{alors}}%
     \renewcommand{\algorithmicend}{\textbf{fin}}%
     % Set other language requirements
  }
  {\end{algorithm}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{englishalgorithm}[H]
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE This is a statement
    \IF{abc}
      \STATE This is another statement
    \ENDIF
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{englishalgorithm}

\begin{frenchalgorithm}[H]
  \caption{Another algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE This is a statement
    \IF{abc}
      \STATE This is another statement
    \ENDIF
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{frenchalgorithm}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You'd have to *define* each of the translated keywords manually. The same would go if you were using the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx).

More about the above changes is briefly discussed in sections **3.14.3 Customization** and **4.4 Customization** of the [`algorithms` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf).
<sub>I don't speak French...</sub>